# Why my notification not work in background when my app is kill and close in android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, kotlin

When my app is open, notification works perfectly but when in background it doesn't work .I want the notification to be displayed even when my app is killed or closed in my phone. But it is not working. Here is my code :-

1) MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt :-

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {


override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {

    showNotification(remoteMessage!!)
    Log.e("fcm", "HElloo Call")

}


@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
private fun showNotification(message: RemoteMessage) {
    val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {


        val i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        val androidChannel = NotificationChannel("1",
                "sdccscsc", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        androidChannel.enableLights(true)
        androidChannel.enableVibration(true)
        androidChannel.lightColor = Color.GREEN
        androidChannel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "1")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(message.data["title"])
                .setContentText(message.data["message"])
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.main_logo)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        manager.createNotificationChannel(androidChannel)
    }


    val i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(message.data["title"])
            .setContentText(message.data["message"])
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.main_logo)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    manager.notify(0, builder.build())

}
```

Comment: did u read this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Comment: yes i already read that doc. @Nilesh

Comment: you need to send notification data in **`data payload`** to get value if your app not in backgroung

Comment: please describe in code? @Nilesh

Comment: did you solve it @maulik

Comment: i solve it but there is another issue create , in oreo os its doesn't show my notification @Nilesh Rathod

Comment: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/214

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There are two types of **Message types**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

1. **Notification message**

> FCM automatically displays the message to end-user devices on behalf of the client app. Notification messages have a predefined set of user-visible keys and an optional data payload of custom key-value pairs.

2. **Data message**

> Client app is responsible for processing data messages. Data messages have only custom key-value pairs.

[as per my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51129699/why-my-notification-not-work-in-background-when-my-app-is-kill-and-close-in-andr/51129799#comment89244260_51129699)

You need to send notification  data in  **Data messages**

**SAMPLE FORMAT**

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"your token",
    "data":{
      "key1" : "value1",
      "key2" : "value2",
      "key3" : "value4",
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    try {
        intent.putExtra("ID",object.getString("data"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "Your_channel";

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Your Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        notificationChannel.setDescription("Description");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }


    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorDarkBlue))
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);

    notificationManager.notify(1000, notificationBuilder.build());
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your logcat if you are receiving the notification. IS your notification being displayed in the system tray?